# Why "some@mail" applies :valid pseudo class?

Tags: html, css, input, email-validation

I have an email input field.
I have css rules for `:valid` and `:invalid` states.
Why does `"some@mail"` make this field valid?
Why it's not waiting for `".com"`?
Is there any way to make it behave normally?

Previously, I used JS for these purposes.
Today I'd like to resolve this without JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some@mail` is a valid email address. `mail` here could be a local URL with no top-level domain associated with it.

For instance, at my office we have `http://wiki/` set up to take us to our company wiki. If we wanted to we could set up an email server on this with the URL `example@wiki` - there'd be no `.com` because there is no TLD here at all.

Wikipedia has a pretty good list of [valid email address examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses), where they include the following example in this format:

> - `admin@mailserver1` (local domain name with no [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain))

Comment: Thank you for  your answer.

Comment: [mail will soon be a public TLD in its own right](https://www.namecheap.com/domains/new-tlds/explore.aspx?keyword=mail&CategoryId=&AvailableIds=0&watchpreorderkeyword=&checklist=&sortexpression=&revertIds=&Extensions=0)